# Phraseology for book worms

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a concise phraseology for when somebody dives their nose evermore into books until the book eats them whole?  Sort of like the lesson telling that you can sometimes be too well-read in life.

Comment: I have never heard of being eaten whole by a book, but I know people who devour a good book. One possibly relevant word is [bibliophile](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bibliophile).

Comment: 'George is always disappearing into some book or other' is perhaps acceptable.

Comment: Hm, no exact phraseology ?  Well thanks for the advice.  @Edwin, where is that quote from again?

Comment: I can think of idioms for the act of reading a whole book in one sitting, like "Read it from cover to cover" and "couldn't put the book down". But I don't know a word for the general tendency.

Comment: @dante5772 *Is there a concise phraseology in some language or another ...?* Probably

Comment: Lol.  Yeah, there usually is.

Comment: @WeatherVane - You’ve never read the Monster Book of Monsters  :-)

Comment: It was homespun; there are a reasonable number of examples of the metaphor (vs the magical sense) on the internet. [A Google search for "disappeared into a book"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=Mci_XpOsIZLFUqHUn5AL&q=%22disappeared+into+a+book%22&oq=%22disappeared+into+a+book%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICCEQFhAdEB4yCAghEBYQHRAeMggIIRAWEB0QHjoCCAA6BQgAEIMBOgcIABBGEPkBOgQIABAKOgYIABAWEB5Q8gtY30RgtEdoAHAAeACAAWmIAc4NkgEEMjMuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjTiNjjnbjpAhWSohQKHSHqB7IQ4dUDCAk&uact=5) gives a few relevant hits, and you can tinker with the exact phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

You can eat, drink and laugh yourself silly, and in a similar way people have been said to ***read themselves silly***.

> In the old days they would have said of him that he ***read himself silly***. His overstimulated intellectual activity was too much for the strength of his frail organism. (My Past and Thoughts: Memoirs of Alexander Herzen, Vol 3, p280)
>
> Morton, you remember me telling you about a boy what ***read himself silly***? This is him, and blamed if he ain't read himself blind as well. (Stiffs, Melbourne Garahan, p154)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most idiomatic expression for being absorbed by a book (rather than being generally addicted to reading) is **She buried herself in her book.**

> *bury [oneself] in*
>
> ...
>
> - To immerse oneself in a task or project. In this usage, a reflexive pronoun is used between "bury" and "in."
>
>   - *Ever since my breakup with Ben, I've tried to bury myself in my work to keep from crying all day long.*
>   - *You will need to bury yourself in your schoolwork to get a passing grade this semester.*
>
> [[Farlex Dictionary of
>   Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bury+yourself+in)]

An example using 'in one's book' as the prepositional phrase from a credible source is:

> - ... but the Doctor's face was too awful; Tom wouldn't have met his eye for all he was worth, and buried himself in his book again.
>
> [[Tom Brown's School Days; Thomas
>   Hughes](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Tom_Brown%27s_School_Days_(6th_ed).djvu/193)]

'Burying oneself in one's books' and variants, for the overly bookish, would work too.

'**Overly bookish**' is accurate, but very dry.